# unicode in firefox extension

Tags: firefox, localization, firefox-addon

Application works when I am using the following code :

```
    xulschoolhello.greeting.label = Hello World?
```

But when I use Unicode, Application does not work :

```
xulschoolhello.greeting.label = سلام دنیا ?
```

Why does not work?

Comment: What are the example lines supposed to be? Properties file definitions (kinda looks like it)? DTD definitions? Javascript assignments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a problem loading that string in my extension in a xul file from `chrome://`. Make sure you are not overriding the encoding (UTF-8 by default). See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/International_characters_in_XUL_JavaScript) for more information.

To make sure, change your XUL's first line to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

In case you are using this in a properties file, make sure you save the .properties file in utf-8 format. From [Property Files - XUL | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Property_Files#Escape_non-ASCII_Characters):

> **Non-ASCII Characters, UTF-8 and escaping**
>
> Gecko 1.8.x (or later) supports property files encoded in UTF-8. You
>   can and should write non-ASCII characters directly without escape
>   sequences, and save the file as UTF-8 without BOM. Double-check the
>   save options of your text editor, because many don't do this by
>   default. See Localizing extension descriptions for more details.
>
> In some cases, it may be useful or needed to use escape sequences to
>   express some characters. Property files support escape sequences of
>   the form: \uXXXX , where XXXX is a Unicode character code. For
>   example, to put a space at the beginning or end of a string (which
>   would normally be stripped by the properties file parser), use \u0020
>   .